# Flutter route transition strange behavior

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm using navigator push to my widget and when i click on my button i see my new screen with a transparent background and behind my previous screen. After less than 1 second background is not transparent anymore.

```dart
Navigator.push(
 context,
 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Planified(
   form: intervention, 
   element: e.value
 )
),
                                          )
```

Could you help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a transparent background try page builder

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false, //or true if you want it as opaque
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Planified(
      form: intervention, 
      element: e.value,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I don't want it, actually i want a simple transition. It works nice on named route but not with simple push. Opaque to true Can fix it or it's already default value ?

Comment: Opaque to true should work. Whats inside the Planified. Check if has a scaffold and a background color too